# Control Responsive Images

Tags: images

I noticed on my site that the images I'm using are presented in html as having variants, this is causing some images to look terrible on smaller screen mobile phones. I extracted the html:

```
https://dev.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/catheaderimage-category-324x324.jpg 324w, 
https://dev.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/catheaderimage-category-150x150.jpg 150w, 
https://dev.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/catheaderimage-category-300x300.jpg 300w, 
https://dev.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/catheaderimage-category-416x416.jpg 416w, 
https://dev.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/catheaderimage-category-100x100.jpg 100w, 
https://dev.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/catheaderimage-category.jpg 648w
```

I can see the advantage, but is there a way I can alter this? for example just to have two sizes, the minimum being 700x700?

I tried altering the Media Settings> Images Sizes, but this appears to make no differnces.

I'm using Wordpress 4.9.4 with Woocommerce 3.3.3 and Storefront 2.2.8 with a personal child theme.